# Substracting two SUM from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like your help regarding a query I can't seem to obtain in one single query.

```
Table timeaccount

Field   Type
id      mediumint(8)   --> Primary key autoincrement
user    varchar(40)    --> user, e.g. 'john.fisher'
type    varchar(15)    --> can only be 'SUM' or 'SUBSTRACT'
minutes smallint(5)    --> an amount of minutes
```

This represents time-accounting for workers where each record says how many minutes a worker(field 'user') has added or substracted from his balance (according to field 'type').

I just want to obtain in one single query the balance from a specific worker, in pseudo-sql it would be:

```
select sum(minutes) from timeaccount where worker = 'john.fisher' and type = 'SUM'
-
select sum(minutes) from timeaccount where worker = 'john.fisher' and type = 'SUBSTRACT'

as balance
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively:

```
SELECT SUM(minutes * case type when 'SUBTRACT' then -1 else 1 end) AS balance
FROM timeaccount
WHERE worker = 'john.fisher' and type in ('SUM','SUBTRACT')
```

Comment: I very much like the elegance of using the multiply-by-inverse trick to use only one SUM, which I expect to have better performance than using two SUM, that is why I mark your answer as Accepted although I very much appreciate MichaelRushton and others answers as I've learned from those as well. Thanks!

Comment: Also you are using a CASE where an IF would have been enough, but I appreciate it as an useful example for a situation where 'type' could have more than just two possible values.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(type = 'SUM', minutes, 0)) -
  SUM(IF(type = 'SUBTRACT', minutes, 0)) AS balance
FROM timeaccount
WHERE worker = 'john.fisher'
```

Comment: In the second SUM the you wrote minutes as string (with quotes). the query probably won't work

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT (SUM_VAL - SUBSTRACT_VAL) as balance FROM
(
 select sum(minutes) AS SUM_VAL FROM timeaccount WHERE worker = 'john.fisher' AND type =     'SUM', 
 select sum(minutes) AS SUBSTRACT_VAL FROM timeaccount WHERE worker = 'john.fisher' AND type = 'SUBSTRACT'
) t1
```

Comment: I think the ansswer by @MichaelRushton is more maintainable (readable, quicker to understand) but this one is a good way to do a similar thing with different tables, e.g. from TIMEACCOUNT for first line and from LUNCH for 2nd.

Comment: Upvoted this for providing an alternative solution that can be used in similar problem, as noted by Karl.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select sum(if(type = 'SUM', minutes, 0)) - sum(if(type = 'SUBSTRACT', minutes, 0)) as balance from timeaccount where worker = 'john.fisher'
```